# Load assembly and its dependencies all in memory

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I need load an assembly and its dependecies dynamically. It's because I need that the assemblies are not locked for any process.

For example, I've created a solution with three projects.

First project is called Entities, that has one class called Person

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Second project is called Business, tah has on class called PersonBusiness. This project referencies the project Entities

```
using Entities;

namespace Business
{
    public class PersonBusiness
    {
        public string GetPersonName(string name)
        {
            return name;
        }

        public Person GetPerson(string name)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.Name = name;
            return person;
        }
     }
}
```

The last project is called Runner. This project loads the assembly of project Businnes dynamically

```
using System.Runtime.Loader;

namespace Runner
{
    public class AssemblyLoader : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        internal AssemblyLoader() : base(isCollectible: true)
        {

        }
    }

    internal class Assembly
    {
        private dynamic Instance { get; set; }
        private AssemblyLoader AssemblyLoader { get; set; }
        private Type AssemblyType { get; set; }

        public void Load()
        {
        
            AssemblyLoader = new AssemblyLoader();

            using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\assemblies\business.dll", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = AssemblyLoader.LoadFromStream(fs);

                AssemblyType = assembly.GetType("Business.PersonBusiness");

                Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(AssemblyType);

                Console.WriteLine(Instance.GetPersonName("Person name"));
                
                // With next line works, but lock tem assembly in memory
                //AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"C:\temp\assemblies\Entities.dll");

                Console.WriteLine(Instance.GetPerson("Person name 2").Name);

            }

        }

        public void Unload()
        {
            AssemblyLoader.Unload();

        }
    }
```

}

It returns the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I tried using AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath. It works, but the assembly is locked.

[Project in github](https://github.com/ercbenck/ProjectLoadAssembly)

Comment: Mandatory reading - all articles by Suzanne Cook on assembly loading - random starting point - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/suzcook/loadfile-vs-loadfrom

Comment: fuslogvw to see assm loading process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the complete assembly dll file into memory, close the file stream (so the file is no longer locked) and then create the Assembly object from the file data in memory? Would that solve your issue?

```
        byte[] dllAssemblyData = null;
        Assembly dllAssembly = null;

        // Read assembly file into byte array
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open("test.dll", FileMode.Open))
        {
            dllAssemblyData = new byte[fs.Length];
            if (fs.Read(dllAssemblyData, 0, dllAssemblyData.Length) != fs.Length)
            {
                // error - count of bytes read does not match file/stream length
                dllAssemblyData = null;
            }
        }

        // Create Assembly from memory
        if (dllAssemblyData != null)
        {
            dllAssembly = Assembly.Load(dllAssemblyData);
        }

        // Use assembly
        if (dllAssembly != null)
        {
            // TODO: use assembly
        }
```